# What is the total cache size in a WebView in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, uiwebview, webview, android-webview

Is there a limit to the size of the cache size of WebView? Is there a difference between iOS and Android webviews?

Answer (score 2):

Well in IOS5 safari the browser cache size is limited to 100MB. This is not a persistent cache.  If you close the webview with the home button it will reduces to zero.

For chrome browser on IOS devices the cache is around 200MB and this is persistent. 
Android 4.1 has around 85MB cache and is also persistent, chrome on android also has 85MB persistent cashe.

With localStorage the caching is very limited on all devices it is around 2.5MB max. And with sessionStorage on android it is unlimited. Android chrome is around 2.5MB. Firefox .unlimited, on IOS its also 2.5MB max. You can [test it here](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/).

IF you talk about HTML5 application cache (AppCache) Chrome mobile for android is almost unlimited. Safari IOS has around 4-10MB  appCache. But [officially](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) it can be unlimited if the user accepts it. A good example of this is the [financial times](http://apps.ft.com/ftwebapp/) mobile site.

Another approach is to use HTML5 database storage for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777968/i-need-a-client-side-browser-database-what-are-my-options?lq=1) IndexDB etc. But a [more supported](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) storage DB to use is web SQL Databasse.