# Javascript (sql or nosql or JSON) client side not HTML5 database libraries?

Tags: javascript, database, json, client-side

We are developing a Javascript based UI(browser based) that needs some data selection  (filtering, sorting, grouping in different levels)I just want to ask about probable Javascript (sql or nosql/JSON) client side (not HTML5) database libraries,  also a performance comparison would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

similar question at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4778046/942855

- http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html

Support level in browsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)#Related_specifications

NO HTML5

- http://www.jstorage.info/
- http://brian.io/lawnchair/plugins/

Comment: thank you
but in the question I asked for  **NOT HTML5** solutions
I mean pure javascript solution not browser storage

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript SQL library. It doest not use IndexedDB and WebSQL (i.e. HTML5 databases), but work in memory. It is relatively fast, because Alasql compiles queries to JavaScript code (see some tests at Github).

Here is the simple sample:

```
<script src="alasql.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var cities = [{city:'Kyiv',country:'Ukraine'}, {city:'Odessa', country:'Ukraine'}, 
                 {city:'Vienna', country:'Austria'}];
   var res = alasql('SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ? \
                       GROUP BY country ORDER BY cnt',[cities]);
   console.log(res);
</script>
```

You can play with [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/19ygosjz/) at jsFiddle.