# Node Webkit and local database

Tags: database, node.js, node-webkit, local-database

I need to store data in a node-webkit application using a database. How can I do that? And how can I make sure that once being compiled it works properly?

I'm new to node-webkit. When I need to store data in node I usually use MongoDB. But it works server-side, and MongoDB need to be installed on the server machine. Node-Webkit works client-side. I need a database working locally and not installed by default in the client running the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777968/i-need-a-client-side-browser-database-what-are-my-options

Answer (score 0):

You have several options out there:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app

`NW.js` is not client-side as it features `node.js`.