# Web SQL DROP/DELETE Table not working

Tags: javascript, sql

I've tried several different commands for clearing my Web SQL Database and none of them work. Just to show you I've assembled all of them into one overkill function. What am I missing?

```
/** Drop Table from Database - Fix This **/
function overKill(tablename){

  var query = "DELETE FROM " + tablename;
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql(query);
  });

  var query = "DELETE * FROM " + tablename;
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql(query);
  });

  var query = "DROP TABLE " + tablename;
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql(query);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE foo",[], 
    function(tx,results){console.log("Successfully Dropped")},
    function(tx,error){console.log("Could not delete")}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

> tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM FormRecords');

Moreover, you [cannot delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7183114/437979) a Web SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE * FROM...
```

does not make sense. use DELETE FROM instead

Answer (score 0):

You last variant is correct. Just for testing you can open your web resourse by Chrome. Then open Resourses -> Web SQL where you can type `DROP TABLE TABLENAME` and check if everething is right.

Answer (score 0):

The follow code should works well:

```
var db = openDatabase(databaseName, "0.1", description, size)

var db.transaction(function (t) {
     t.executeSql("DROP TABLE objectTable",[], 
         function(t,results){
             console.error("Table Dropped")
         },
         function(t,error){
             console.error("Error: " + error.message)
         }
     )
})
```