# Delete Data from Web SQL database whenever phonegap Application's exit event occurs

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I have two Questions:

- What is the exit event of phone-gap Application? I haven't find it yet.
- How to Delete  Data from All the tables whenever exit event occurs? and insert it back from the web service whenever the deviceready() event of phonegap occurs.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [pause event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause). The documentation reads like this:

> The pause event fires when the native platform puts the application into the background, typically when the user switches to a different application.

You can attach a handler to this event like this:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
```

Now the `onPause` method will be called everytime your app is going to the background and you can drop your tables there somewhat [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820189/web-sql-drop-delete-table-not-working):

```
function onPause() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE foo",[], 
            function(tx,results){console.log("Successfully Dropped")},
            function(tx,error){console.log("Could not delete")}
        );
    });
}
```

Assuming the `db` variable holds your WebSQL database and you're trying to drop the table named `foo`.

Comment: Okay. Whenever user switches back to the application, what event is going to be fired in that case? document.ready()? Right?

Comment: If your app is being pulled in the foreground again the [resume event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#resume) is fired. Make sure to take a look at the iOS quirks aswell, if you're working with iOS.

Comment: Also feel free to [vote up and accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped.

Comment: I read the documentation. But it might be costly in terms of efficiency in my case. Now I am using different approach to this. I am now dropping my tables before creating them on device.ready().