# Delete databases (IndexedDB, WebSQL) for file:// schema in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb, web-sql

I've got dozens of databases created running code under file:// schema in Chrome. How can I remove them?

The usual place *Settings - Cookies and sites* doesn't list them :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the Indexeddb database with javascript command. For instance to delete an indexeddb named `dbtest` type in the chrome console:

```
indexedDB.deleteDatabase('_pouch_dbtest')
```

You can check on the ressource tab of the dev tools if it worked with the `Refresh Indexeddb` option:

[image]

For WebSQL, I think it's not that simple (see that [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183049/how-to-delete-a-database-in-web-sql))

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about IndexedDB, but the problem with WebSQL is that it doesn't support database removal.

In Chrome you can remove the database directly from the file system, the path to database folder is like `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\file__0`. Just remove this folder(s).

More answers here: [How to delete a database in WebSQL programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183049/how-to-delete-a-database-in-web-sql)

Comment: Thanks! It's better than nothing, but in actual fact I need that mostly on Ubuntu and Android where I do most of my dev.

I imagine I can find the corresponding path on Ubuntu, but that still leaves Android, and that still leaves IndexedDB.

Thanks again though, gives me something to poke about :-)