# Is there a way in google chrome to allow for more than 4 MB (2 million UTF-16 characters) storage in HTML5 offline storage?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, offline

I have created a hosted app for Chrome and I am wondering if there is any way that I can get more than 4 MB offline storage in Chrome.
I have looked at this post http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/faq.html#faq-app-15 but [one](http://grinninggecko.com/increasing-chromes-offline-application-cache-storage-limit/) says that it is possible to increase Chrome's offline storage by up to ~260MB. Is this really possible? if so, is there any example that illustrates that possibility?

I have also looked at this [stackoverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689939/html5-database-storage-sql-lite-few-questions) and WebSQL DB appears to not have a limit. so is WebSQL DB or IndexedDB an only option for chrome app to store larger offline contents?

Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Quota Management API: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/11/Quota-Management-API-Fast-Facts

Or, if you're creating a hosted app, you can use the `unlimitedStorage` permission to surpass the quota limits: http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide.html

Comment: Not that quota won't apply if you're using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. You'll need to be using IndexedDB, the Filesystem API, or WebDB to take advantage of Quota.