# HTML 5 and Database

Tags: database, html

I am trying to learn HTML 5 and I wanted to know how would HTML 5 deal with database.
I came across Web SQL database but I read that it is not being used much. What would be the simplest way to interact with database?

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689939/html5-database-storage-sql-lite-few-questions) will be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 supports different client-side storage methods which store persistent data **in the browser**.

- Local Storage and session storage http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute
- IndexedDB https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB
- WebSQL (currently still poorly supported and not ready for real use). WebSQL is option only if you target a specific browser (Mobile Safari / iOS). Also it looks like WebSQL will die soon http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Answer (score 2):

To me they are unrelated and HTML5 does not deal with databases. HTML is a language for presenting content. HTML5 has added new features related to semantics, media presentation, and some browser manipulation (like history). http://diveintohtml5.info/ is a great website to learn about the new features in HTML5, and some possible applications in website development.

HTML does not discriminate with regards to content, and doesn't care whether it comes from a database or if you input it by hand. It will treat that content the same.

PHP is an example of a language that interacts with a database.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so if I want to display a table using HTML5 and that table reads values from a database, how would I go about doing this?